# Is it possible (anymore) to open and send Yahoo! emails in Outlook, without a plus account?

Tags: email, thunderbird, microsoft-outlook-2010, yahoo-mail

I have a variety of emails accounts, all of which I frequently use (Yahoo, Gmail, School..) What's frustrating, though, is when I need to frequently consult an account, such as my two Yahoo accounts. I can't log into them simultaneously except in two different browsers, which is a hassle. This, then, brings me to my point: Is it possible to read and send Yahoo! emails through Outlook Express 2010? It used to be possible with programs / addons such as YPOPS!, or in Mozilla Thunderbird with WebMail, but I think that is no logner supported as well.

If it is Mozilla Thunderbird or Outlook 2010, I really don't care, but does anyone know of a client that I can use to read and send email from all of my email addresses, including Yahoo? I don't see what the big hassle with Yahoo is, it can easily be accessed from the webpage, but that is a hassle when you have more than one account. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there is still an issue that prevents Outlook to work natively with Yahoo through IMAP (a security id thing during connection). And POP3, which Outlook supports with Yahoo, is now only available on Yahoo Plus.

But Thunderbird can access Yahoo, Gmail and others natively through IMAP. And as of today, free Yahoo accounts work with IMAP. [See link](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Using_webmail_with_your_email_client) for details. I am personally using 4 accounts, 2 Gmail and 2 Yahoo (both free), with Thunderbird without any extra plug-in or proxy application.

**Configuration screenshots for Yahoo in Thunderbird:**

[image]

The username is the user part of your e-mail address (without the @yahoo.com part).

Comment: Great! I can read my email.. but when I try to send any, I get "An error occurred while sending mail. The mail server responded:  Message Size exceeded. Please check the message and try again." .. any idea why?

Comment: I get the same error too. I usually receive only on my yahoo boxes, so I am not sure. Might be server issues: https://getsatisfaction.com/mozilla_messaging/topics/_message_size_exceeded_sending_from_thunderbird_via_yahoo

Comment: To fix this problem, turn off the SSL/TLS connection security. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am also using Thunderbird to read and send email from a variety of service providers. I use IMAP interface and have no issues sofar. As of recently, Yahoo increased the security requirements for e-mail clients, so you might get a log-in failure. In that case, you need to log-in through the web and enable "unsecure aplications." They will warn you that it is less secure... but with Yahoo as it is in security breaches, it doesn't mean much.